# How to use MIN() function of postgresql using java code

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I need to find the minimum value from a table . How to use that using java.

```
databaseClient.sql("Select MIN (employee_salary) " +
                                    "from " + schema + ".employee_instances where employee_id =:employeeId")
```

This gives me error when i execute my code -

ERROR-

"Column name 'employee_salary' does not exist in column names [min]",

Comment: This has nothing to do with java, your SQL is wrong. `MIN` requires a `GROUP BY` clause to work (afaik) next to that this piece of code wouldn't throw that error so it must be in the code you wrote downstream for mapping.

Comment: Same query is working in pgadmin without groupBY clause.

Comment: nonetheless it isn't **this** code that results in the error but your mapping code. Also notice that there is a space between `MIN` and `(` not sure if R2DBC (or the PostgresSQL driver) chokes on that.

Comment: @M.Deinum: as written, the query will not require a group by as it doesn't select any ungrouped columns (and PostgreSQL will not chocke on the space between min and the `/`).

Comment: @developer: it seems your Java code tries to retrieve a column named `employee_salary` but your query does not have such a column (only a column named `min`). You will need a column alias if that is the case:  `min(employee_salary) as employee_salary`

Comment: That wasn't what i ws implying in my second comment (reading is an art). The code you post isn't the code that leads to the error... Your mapping code is (which I now explained for third time). As stated the driver might choke on this doesn't mean postgresql will choke. on it the driver might. And it appears as if tha tis the case as it has a column named MIN and not hte one you expect. So remove the space, try again, else use an index to map instead of the column name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right I did the same, used alias It worked. 
My mistake I was retrieving with employee_salary but the column name returned was min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019153/how-to-use-min-function-of-postgresql-using-java-code/75097871#comment132388314_75019153) above helped resolve my problem:

> it seems your Java code tries to retrieve a column named `employee_salary` but your query does not have such a column (only a column named `min`). You will need a column alias if that is the case: `min(employee_salary) as employee_salary`